# Logging without newline in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

How to log this stream of data without a newline each time?

```
websocket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log(msg.content);
  }
});
```

Above would result in:

```
> streamedContent-1
> streamedContent-2
> streamedContent-3..
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
> streamedContent-n // this line getting updated on each refresh, no new line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use c++ `stdout` methods inside a Node app to "edit" a line in runtime.

```js
process.stdout.clearLine()
process.stdout.write(`\r${msg.content}`);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. How would you color or format stdout by the way, since console.log hides that complexity for you?

Comment: There is a node module for that it's called `chalk` i think.

Comment: `process.stdout.write('\r' + chalk.red(msg.content));`